# Google Cloud DNS: Is it possible to have multiple TXT records for a single domain?

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I have been asked to create a new TXT record for domain verification.  I currently have a domain level TXT record used for SPF.  When I enter in a second record, I get an error that the resource already exists.

Is there a method to create a second TXT record in Cloud DNS for a single domain?

Comment: Make as many as you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not create a duplicate record set entry. If you try it will give you "[Error: The resource with that name already exists](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/troubleshooting#alreadyexists)"

Each individual record in Google Cloud DNS is treated as a record set. You can add two values or strings to the record set for the same DNS name by adding a space between the first value and the second value.

For example, you can add multiple Records (in your case TXT) per Resource Record set by clicking **`+ Add item`** within your TXT record set as shown below:
[image]

Here is the list of [Resource limit](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas#resource_limits).